# Could not load file or Aseembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

In my one .net project on building project i am getting below error.

My one project say "X" using the reference of another project say "Y" On building my solution i got the below error:-

Cannot register assembly X.dll.Could not load file or assembly 'Y, Version=1.0.0.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=80955c93367666f4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I'd recommend you to [Enable the Fusion Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) and examine it.  In most situations that's more than enough.

Comment: what is the assembly name?

Comment: using framework 3.5 for both.but assembly version is different.For one project(X) assembly version is 2.0.0.0 and another(for Y) its 1.0.0.0

Comment: @Priyanka: If you don't need this question posted anymore, request to have the question deleted, **don't try to erase the question**.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the references of your solution. That link must be broken with a caution icon on the assembly.

OR

As comment on my answer 
"It can also be a reference of the reference. As it said or *one of its dependencies*"

Comment: No. It can also be a reference of the reference. As it said _or one of its dependencies_